# Best Data Modeling and Web Site Wireframe tool for web application

Tags: asp.net, html, database, web

Which is the best Data Modeling and Web Site Wireframe tool for web application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) is very nice, and has a free web based version (it nags you every once in a while, asking if you'd like to purchase).

The nice thing about this product is that it's intentionally unstyled, which forces you to focus on moving forward with your layout's concept, rather than waste time getting it pixel perfect.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com) for modeling, it is powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_OverView.aspx), released as part of the Expression Studio, looks like it could be quite good, allowing you to build interactive prototypes, hooked into your datamodels with minimal effort, collect feedback, etc.